# Express get requests

Tags: angular, express

I am making a site with angular 4, express and mongo. It is my first site and I am not really sure how to use get requests. I know that they are for requesting data from the server. So i used them for my request to the database. The problem with that is if the user is on the `localhost:3000/games/1` if he refreshes the page he does not recieve the site. Instead he recieves only the info from the database. How do i fix this? Any help would be appreaciated.

```
this.Router
  .get("/games/:id", (req, res) => this.controller.getAll(req, res))
  .get("/*", this.controller.getSite);
```

Above is an expmple of my problem if i am on games/:id and i refresh i only get the db info and not the webpage

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: @Akshay I added a small piece of code to demonstrate better what i mean. And how i have made the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always keep the URLs of API and Views different, for example if user visits `example.com/games/1` to view the webpage than the API to get the data should not be same, keep it something like `example.com/api/games/1` which would resolve this issue.